# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' could be due to requests

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a table in the website: https://www.enr.com/economics/historical_indices/construction_cost_index_history

However, I keep getting the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' could be due to requests"

My code worked before but suddenly it stopped working and would not recognize the table...maybe it has to do with the website server blocking access to my scraping??? Here's the code:

def web_scraper(url):

```
# Create object page
page = requests.get(url)

# parser-lxml = Change html to Python friendly format
# Obtain page's information
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

# Obtain information from tag <table>
table1 = soup.find('table')

# Obtain every title of columns with tag <th>
headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(title)

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

# Create a for loop to fill mydata
for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]: # start the selection by skipping the headers
    row_data = j.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text.strip() for i in row_data]
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = row

return df
```

web_scraper('https://www.enr.com/economics/historical_indices/construction_cost_index_history')

Comment: That page is behind a login. Are you logging in before trying to scrape the table?

Comment: Yes, I logged in before scraping the table. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are having an empty table1. The URL you provided had a login page...

Comment: Yes, I have to log in before scraping. Does that matter?

Comment: Yes, basically you are scraping the login page. It doesn’t matter if you are logging in on your computer, since you are reaching the url through requests.

Comment: So, what would you suggest I do?